# Custom Path for Save Versions

Tags: blend-files, path, file-browser

I love the save versions feature but not lovin' these versions to be saved next to my file.. I prefer them to be saved in another hard-drive or folder as well..

[image: many versions]

I can't find a configuration to change the path of these versions.. does It exist yet or should I suggest It? :)

[image: configs not found]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an addon written by Jonathan Stroem to allow saving the backup blend files into a subfolder. I'm sure you could easily modify it to write the file somewhere else on your system.

[Config blender to save backup files in subfolder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/config-blender-to-save-backup-files-in-subfolder)

Comment: there ya go https://pastebin.com/3yVZrZMg just change the line 42 with the folder you want to save all your back ups. This is for linux