# I accidently saved a file

Tags: blend-files

I was deleting some stuff because I wanted to export it one object but then I accidentally saved the file out of habit, and now all my other items are deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. **How can we help?** Could you add a possible solution which you have in mind or a more detailed question? Once a file is overwritten, it cannot be undone, unless you have an unusual operating system. If you haven't specified version saving (blend1, blend2 ...) then there will also be no backups.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this. At least I rendered some photos of it. :D

Comment: Setup Blenders [backup functionality](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/preferences/file.html?highlight=blend1#save-load)! Read this [blogpost on recovering work](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/3-ways-recover-lost-work). This [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6940/30849) may also be of interest to you.