# Save Backups to Subdirectory

Tags: python, blend-files

Is there a way to set the backup directory for Blender 2.8?

Previously, I used the addon from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6940/30849), but it is deprecated for 2.8.

Has a builtin way been implemented?