# Addon for blender to save backup files in subfolder

Tags: python, add-on, blend-files

I have found this [Plugin](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/config-blender-to-save-backup-files-in-subfolder) to move the Blender version files to a subdirectory, which is exactly what I need, but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore. Is there any other option to move the version files to a subdirectory or an fix for the Plugin?

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, we are a question and answer site aimed at providing users with localized assistance along the way, rather than solve the whole issue for them by presenting ready-made solutions. For commissioning work, job posts or hiring someone, there is a [Jobs section over at Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/c/14). Otherwise, could rephrase your post to read more like a direct inquiry showing efforts towards your goal, rather than ask for someone to do it for you, so it can be reopened?

Comment: have you tried twigho's version? (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296532/107598). It doesn't run on Blender 3.6. I guess it's because the Python version got an update. Anyway, the fix is easy just move the 2 lines `if __name__ == "__main__":` and `register()` (line 14+15) down to the end of the file (line 62). The 3 functions (`def ...`) must be before the main function.

Comment: oh wait, for testing I just ran the script and haven't installed it as add-on. It probably works without a change when you install it as an add-on. Save it to a file and then Edit > User Preferences > Add-ons ...

Comment: It wasn't my intent to make a job offering or get anyone to work, and I am sorry if it came across like that. Also, thank you, Blunder, for the Help.